# VS2013: never put bin directory in source control, but it caused build fail

Tags: c#, dll, version-control, bin

I'm new in Visual Studio 2013 (C#). I know in general it should be avoid putting bin directory in source control. However, in my bin directory, there are lots of dll files. Without this dlls, I can't build my project.

I thought maybe I should create a directory, such as 'lib' to store the dlls. But the fact is NuGet always put dll into the bin directory. Should I manually move the dll from bin to lib?

All I want is to simply put all source codes, resource files and dll files to source control (git). Then my team-mates can pull the project then build it in their machine.

**edit on 1/4/2015**: provide further details

For example, I installed log4net thru NuGet. After finished, I found 3 new files existed in bin directory:

- log4net.dll
- log4net.xml
- log4net.dll.refresh

I tried to remove bin directory from my project, then rebuild my project, and hope to see that a new bin directory would be built and all dll/pdb/etc files would come back. But unfortunately it didn't happen.

In my understanding, the ideal process would be:

1. add reference/install package, then certain config info would be recorded and according files would be installed to bin directory;
2. when build, according lib files would be referenced from bin, if such files not found, VS would get the reference info from some place other than bin and download them again. So that's one of the reasons why we don't need to put bin into source control.

However, I found that's not true in my project.

Actually according to the official .gitignore, I found bin directory as build results is filtered ([Bb]in/). That is to say, even VS knows such directory should be ignored.

Maybe some wrong setting within my project?

Comment: Never put the `bin` directory into source control. Instead, either put the packages into source control, or else allow NuGet to _restore_ missing packages during the build.

Comment: NuGet puts things into /packages; it is *building the project* that typically puts them in /bin - unless there's something very unusual happening. Can you indicate which NuGet package is being problematic?